# How to do link to src from examples in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I see this link
https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/examples/FacebookTabsExample/package.json#L11
but it copy/paste to node_modules and when I want to change in src you should always do npm i ?
Is it any other way
Issue https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/357

Answer (score 0):

As I understand rn(watchman) has problems with symlinks so temporary solution

node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --projectRoots /Users/butuzgol/Playground/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/,/Users/butuzgol/Playground/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/examples

and in

var ScrollableTabView = require('../index');